# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'. `np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`

Tags: tensorflow, fastapi, attributeerror

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

MODEL = load_model("../models/1")
CLASS_NAMES = ["Early Blight", "Late Blight", "Healthy"]

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    image_batch = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    predictions = MODEL.predict(image_batch)
    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
    return {
        'class': predicted_class,
        'confidence': float(confidence)
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.
`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

I upgraded to the latest version of `numpy` and `tensorflow`, but the issue persists.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please include the full error traceback. It will tell you wxactly where `np.object` is being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.24 of `numpy`, `np.object` is deprecated, and needs to be replaced with `object`- that's what the release note says ([numpy release notes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations)). You either need to update this in your code or another package you're using.
Since you're using a trained model, one solution is just to revert back to `numpy=1.23.4` and it will solve the issue:

```
pip install numpy==1.23.4
```

P.S. In `numpy 1.23.4` it's still deprecated but not removed from the package altogether, so it will still throw the warning but it will work. If you don't want the warning either you can go back to `numpy==1.19` but that will likely generate issues with other dependencies, so I advice using `numpy==1.23.4` and use `warnings` library to ignore the warning messeges

Here's my test code:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
print("Version: ",np.__version__)
print("np.object: ",np.object)
```

Output:

```
Version:  1.23.4
np.object:  <class 'object'>
```